# Valid SOQL that returns results does not return when run dynamically

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I have an Apex class that runs a dynamic SOQL query. The logs say "Aggregations:0". However, when I copy/paste the executed query directly from the log into developer console, it returns multiple records. This is not a test class; the data should be there.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT Id, Opportunity.Name, Campaign_Name__c, Campaign_Status__c, Lamar_Panel_Number__c, Company__c, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Tracking_Number__c, Materials_Received__c, Date_Installed__c, Panel_Maintenance__c, Contract_Sequence__c, Contract_Start_Date__c, Contract_End_Date__c, Agency_Contract__c, Quantity, Media_Type__c, Media_Style__c, Design_Name__c, Shipping_Date__c, Material_ETA__c, Scheduled_Install_Date__c, Scheduled_Takedown_Date__c, Takedown_Date__c, Customer_Name__c, Customer_Number__c, Advertiser_Name__c, Advertiser_Number__c, Contract_Number__c FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Opportunity.Name LIKE '%max%' ORDER BY Start_Date__c DESC LIMIT 100
```

Again, this is a DIRECT copy/paste from the log that says "SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN". This is not the string that I am passing to DataBase.query().

EDIT: Here is the Apex

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<OpportunityLineItem> search(String status, String dateType, Date startDate, Date endDate, String custNum, String advNum, String campaign, String contract, String sequence){
        //constructs a SOQL query in String format based on incoming paramters. Blank paramters are left as empty strings and will not affect the SOQL string

        Map<String,String> statusMap = new Map<String,String>{'status2' => 'Contracted','status3' => 'Shipped','status4' => 'Arrived','status5' => 'Installed','status6' => 'Complete'};
        Map<String,String> startdateMap = new Map<String,String>{'status1' => '', 'status2' => 'Contract_Start_Date__c','status3' => 'Shipping_Date__c','status4' => 'Materials_Received__c','status5' => 'Date_Installed__c','status6' => 'Takedown_Date__c'};
        Map<String,String> enddateMap = new Map<String,String>{'status1' => '', 'status2' => 'Contract_End_Date__c','status3' => 'Shipping_Date__c','status4' => 'Materials_Received__c','status5' => 'Date_Installed__c','status6' => 'Takedown_Date__c'};

        //if no parameters are sent, then no WHERE clause is inserted at all. if any parameters are not empty, this string is updated
        String whereQuery = '';
        String statusQuery = '';
        String custQuery = '';
        String advQuery = '';
        String campaignQuery = '';
        String contractQuery = '';
        String dateQuery = '';
        String sequenceQuery = '';

        //check each of the incoming parameters, and if not empty, create a string that will be concatenated to the final query
        if (status != 'status1') {
            statusQuery = ' Campaign_Status__c = \'' + statusMap.get(status) + '\' AND';
            whereQuery = 'WHERE';
            String startdateQuery = '';
            String enddateQuery = '';
            
            if (startDate != null) {
                startdateQuery = ' ' + startdateMap.get(status) + ' >= ' + String.valueOf(startDate) + ' AND';
            }
            if (endDate != null) {
                enddateQuery = ' ' + enddateMap.get(status) + ' <= ' + String.valueOf(endDate) + ' AND';
            }
            dateQuery = startdateQuery + enddateQuery;
        }

        if (custNum != '') {
            custQuery = ' Customer_Number__c = ' + custNum + ' AND';
            whereQuery = 'WHERE';
            if (advNum != '') {
                advQuery = ' Advertiser_Number__c = ' + advNum + ' AND';
            }
        }

        if (campaign != '') {
            campaignQuery = ' Opportunity.Name LIKE \'%' + campaign + '%\' AND';
            whereQuery = 'WHERE';
        }

        if (contract != '') {
            if (sequence != '') {
                contractQuery = ' Contract_Sequence__c = \'' + contract + '-' + sequence + '\' AND';
            } else {
                contractQuery = ' Contract_Number__c = \'' + contract + '\' AND';
            }
            whereQuery = 'WHERE';
        }

        //concatenate the strings into the WHERE clause of the query
        String queryString = whereQuery + statusQuery + custQuery + advQuery + campaignQuery + contractQuery + dateQuery;
        system.debug('here is the initial query string: ' + queryString);
        //if the WHERE clause is not empty, trim off the last AND
        if (queryString.length() > 0) {
            Integer len = querystring.length() - 3;
            queryString = queryString.substring(0,len);
        }
        
        queryString = 'SELECT Id, Opportunity.Name, Campaign_Name__c, Campaign_Status__c, Lamar_Panel_Number__c, Company__c, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Tracking_Number__c, Materials_Received__c, ' +
        'Date_Installed__c, Panel_Maintenance__c, Contract_Sequence__c, Contract_Start_Date__c, Contract_End_Date__c, Agency_Contract__c, Quantity, Media_Type__c, Media_Style__c, Design_Name__c, Shipping_Date__c, ' +
        'Material_ETA__c, Scheduled_Install_Date__c, Scheduled_Takedown_Date__c, Takedown_Date__c, Customer_Name__c, Customer_Number__c, Advertiser_Name__c, Advertiser_Number__c, Contract_Number__c FROM OpportunityLineItem ' + queryString + 'ORDER BY Start_Date__c DESC LIMIT 100';
        system.debug('here is the final query string: ' + queryString);
        
        List<OpportunityLineItem> searchResults = DataBase.query(queryString);
        
        return searchResults;
```

Comment: Can you [edit](/posts/348791/edit) your question and add the Apex Code as well?

Comment: Try to debug the results of this query.

Comment: This is most likely to do with sharing and the executing user not having access to the records.